# Want a different approach to this question, assuming I don't know about independent events.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> Two dice are thrown n times in succession. What is the probability of obtaining double six at least once?

I am aware of the solution using independent events. Explanation is already provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413645/two-dice-are-thrown-n-times-in-succession-what-is-the-probability-of-obtaining).

This question comes from 2nd chapter of the book 'First Course in Probability' by Sheldon M. Ross, and till now 'independent events' have not been reached, which is in the 3rd chapter.

Therefore, I want to know what other way is there to solve this question where I don't need the knowledge of independent events to multiply $(35/36)$ $n$ number of times to reach the solution:

$1 - (35/36)^n$

I know how it is being subtracted from 1, but is there any way to reach $(35/36)^n$ using Permutation, Combination or anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: This is just a binomial distribution, with success probability $\frac 1{36}$.

Comment: I am not aware of distribution functions. Can you provide a solution without it, and based on the basics?

Comment: I don't know what you consider the basics.  You need some technique for analyzing multiple events...independence is about as basic as it gets.  I suggest, discussing it with your instructor.

Comment: I meant, since independent event has not arrived yet on the 2nd chapter, I was wondering if there's a solution that does not considers independent events and solves the problem using inclusion-exclusion principle or something.

Comment: How would you do it for $n=2$?  The same technique should work.

Comment: I am thinking it would be solved using @ZevConoles way in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52384/while-calculating-why-do-i-get-1-pac-neq-pa). Do you think it will work?

Comment: You can count the strings, I suppose (though I really don't see that this is all that different a method).  Since each specified roll sequence is equally probable, there are $35^n$ strings in which $(6,6)$ never occurs. As there are $36^n$ sequences all together, the probability that no $(6,6)$ ever occurs is $\left(\frac {35}{36}\right)^n$ and you want the complementary event.

Comment: Of course, saying that each string is equally probable is the same as independence.  But, maybe this feels like a different method.

Comment: I figured it out. Though counting the strings make it longer, the assumption of independent events goes out of window, and returns the same solution. I was trying to understand the underneath intution. Thank you very much!